# Swift KVO on an object conforming to a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, key-value-observing

I have a protocol (X) and a class (A) that implements protocol X:

```
protocol X, NSObjectProtocol {
   var toBeObserved: MyCustomClass? { get}
}

class A: NSObject, X {
   var toBeObserved: MyCustomClass?
   ...
}
```

in another class I want to observe the variable `toBeObserved`:

```
class B {
    ...
    var instanceConformingToX: X <-note: not A but simply the protocol X
    ...
    func someFunc() {
       self.observation = self.observe(\.instanceConformingToX.toBeObserved) { (observed, change) in
       ...
       }
    } 
}
```

}

Everything piece of the equation here is or conform to NSObject, so I expect to be able to KVO `toBeObserved` but instead I get a runtime crash:

```
Fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath Swift.KeyPath<MyAppName.B, MyFramework.A>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Everything that needs to be exposed to KVO has to marked as `@objc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to mark the observed property as `@objc` and `dynamic`. As [Using Key-Value Observing in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift) says:

> Mark properties that you want to observe through key-value observing with both the `@objc` attribute and the `dynamic` modifier.

The protocol and participating classes will need to be marked `@objc`, too. E.g.:

```
class MyCustomClass: NSObject { ... }

@objc protocol X: NSObjectProtocol {
    @objc dynamic var toBeObserved: MyCustomClass? { get }
}

class A: NSObject, X {
    var toBeObserved: MyCustomClass? = MyCustomClass()
}

class B: NSObject {
    @objc var x: X = A()

    var token: NSKeyValueObservation?

    func addObserver() {
        token = observe(\.x.toBeObserved) { object, _ in
            print(object)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does the `@objc dynamic` also need to be on `A.toBeObserved`? I wouldn't think that conforming to X would be enough (since that could happen after A is compiled). (Haven't tested, though; just fells that way.)

Comment: No, it apparently doesn’t. I’ve tested the above and works. Obviously, if you didn’t have protocol, you would, though. But I was trying to reduce to bare minimum...

Comment: I was missing the @objc in ` @objc var x: X = A()`, nice one ;) thanks