# Swift - How to use KVO's 'observe' method on protocol

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need an observable property on certain view controllers in my application, I'm trying to standardize this through a protocol.

```
protocol MyProtocol: UIViewController {
    dynamic var observeMe: Bool { get set }
}
```

But when trying to observe the property like so:

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
if let observableViewController = viewController as? MyProtocol {
    observableViewController.observe(\.observeMe, options: [.old, .new], changeHandler: { object, change in
        // Do something
    })
}
```

Xcode throws the compiler error:

> "Member 'observe' cannot be used on value of protocol type
> 'MyProtocol'; use a generic constraint instead"

Comment: Does your `MyProtocol` have associated types?

Comment: @Alexander no, the code as-is gives the compiler error I mentioned.

Comment: The `dynamic` modifier won't help you in a protocol, a class can implement your protocol without marking the property as `dynamic`. There are better ways to implement the Observable pattern with protocols, than via KVO.

Comment: @Cristik Care to share those better ways?

Comment: Property wrappers (e.g. ObservedObject/@Published), for example, or custom Observer pattern implementation.

Comment: BTW, here's a similar question, asked a while ago, maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548323/swift-kvo-on-an-object-conforming-to-a-protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a function and apply the generic constraint to it.

In Swift 5.7 you can simply do:

```swift
func observeViewController(_ vc: some MyProtocol) {
  vc.observe(\.observeMe, options: [.old, .new], changeHandler: { object, change in
  })
}
```

Then you can call it:

```swift
let viewController = UIViewController()
if let observableViewController = viewController as? MyProtocol {
  observeViewController(viewController)
}
```

Prior to Swift 5.7, `some MyProtocol` is not supported and you need to use type erasure:

```swift
class AnyMyProtocol: MyProtocol & UIViewController {
  var observeMe: Bool

  private var base: MyProtocol

  init(_ base: MyProtocol) {
    self.base = base
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}

func observeViewController(_ vc: MyProtocol) {
  vc.observe(\.observeMe, options: [.old, .new], changeHandler: { object, change in
  })
}
```

And call it like so:

```swift
let viewController = UIViewController()
observeViewController(vc: AnyMyProtocol(base: observableViewController))
```

By the way, you will receive a warning reading:

`Passing reference to non-'@objc dynamic' property 'observeMe' to KVO method 'observe(_:options:changeHandler:)' may lead to unexpected behavior or runtime trap`

But in your case you can't declare it as `@objc` because an `@objc` protocol can't inherit from a non-protocol type.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
import Foundation

protocol MyProtocol {
    dynamic var observeMe: Bool { get set }
}

class Test : NSObject, MyProtocol {
    @objc var observeMe: Bool = true
    private var observeMeObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        observeMeObservation = self.observe(\.observeMe, changeHandler: { [weak self] (_, _) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            print("observeMe : \(self.observeMe)")
        })
    }
    
    func doSomeChanges() {
        self.observeMe = false
        self.observeMe = true
    }
    
    deinit {
        observeMeObservation?.invalidate()
    }
}

let test = Test()
test.doSomeChanges()
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I need to access `observeMe` through the protocol, I don't know who `self` can be, that's why on my question I'm doing `if let observableViewController = viewController as? MyProtocol`.

Comment: The error is clear enough - `Member 'observe' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'MyProtocol'`. It's not allowed. You need to observe on a type that conforms to the protocol.